# Passing an ID to a function using Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: javascript, function, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I've got myself a bit confused here, so I'm looking for a bit of guidance.

Basically, I have an app which talks to an API and gather information on 'Tours'. The first request retrieves the 3 tours (ID and Name) and stores it in a database, the second request should then loop through the 3 tours (using the Tour Detail API endpoint) and get the information (including lon/lat details) of each tour.

Now, that works fine.

The problem I am having, is that each tour has it's own ID number. Unfortunately, the second and third tours are using the same ID number as the 1st when they go into the database.

So I'm guessing I'm not passing in the ID correctly.

Can anyone help to get this looping round properly?

Code below for the whole function....

```
// get tours and add them to DB
function loadTours() {

    // get the species data
    var loader = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
        timeout: 30000 /* in milliseconds */
    });

    loader.onload = function() {
        // get the JSON response
        var tours = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        var db = Ti.Database.open('myDB');
        // truncate the tours table
        db.execute('DELETE FROM tours');

        for (var i = 0; i < tours.length; i++) {

            // Get the data from the feed
            var tourID = tours[i].nid;
            var tourTitle = tours[i].node_title.toUpperCase();

            Ti.API.info(tourID + ' ' + tourTitle);


            // check if images have been uploaded
            if (tours[i].app_image.uri) {
                // removed
            } else {
                var tourImageFullPath = "";
            }


            // add the tours to the SQL
            db.execute('INSERT INTO tours (tourNID, tourName, tourImageURI) VALUES (?,?,?)', tourID, tourTitle, tourImageFullPath);

            // lets do a loop through and insert the tour details
            var getTourDetails = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
                timeout: 30000 /* in milliseconds */
            });

            getTourDetails.onload = function() {
                var tourDetails = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                db.execute('DELETE FROM tourdetails');
                for (var i = 0; i < tourDetails.length; i++) {
                    var tourNID = tourID;
                    var tourSpeciesID = tourDetails[i].node_field_data_field_tour_item_nid;
                    var tourType = tourDetails[i].node_field_data_field_tour_item_type;

                    if (tourDetails[i].Latitude.length === 0){
                        var tourLat = '';
                    } else {
                        var tourLat = tourDetails[i].Latitude;
                    }

                    if (tourDetails[i].Longitude.length === 0){
                        var tourLon = '';
                    } else {
                        var tourLon = tourDetails[i].Longitude;
                    }

                    if (tourDetails[i].node_field_data_field_tour_item_type.length === 0){
                        var tourItemType = '';
                    } else {
                        var tourItemType = tourDetails[i].node_field_data_field_tour_item_type;
                    }

                    var tourItemTitle = tourDetails[i].node_field_data_field_tour_item_title.toUpperCase();
                    db.execute('INSERT INTO tourdetails (tourNID, tourItemID, tourLon, tourLat, tourItemTitle, tourItemType) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)', tourNID, tourSpeciesID, tourLon, tourLat, tourItemTitle, tourItemType);
                    Ti.API.info('TOUR: ' + tourNID + ' ' + tourSpeciesID + ' ' + tourLon + ' ' + tourLat + ' ' + tourItemTitle + ' ' + tourItemType);
                }
            };

            getTourDetails.open("GET", "https://www.myapi.com/tour?nid=" + tourID);

            // change the loading message
            MainActInd.message = 'Downloading Data';
            // show the indicator
            MainActInd.show();

            getTourDetails.send();

        }

        // now load the map markers
        getMapMarkers();

    }; //onload - end the JSON fetch and process for species

    // Sets the HTTP request method, and the URL to get data from
    loader.open("GET", "https://www.myapi.com/tours");

    // change the loading message
    MainActInd.message = 'Downloading Data';
    // show the indicator
    MainActInd.show();

    loader.onerror = function() {
        // do something if an error
        MainActInd.hide();
        //alert('tours data error');

        var errorDialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
            message: 'We are having an issue importing the Tour data. Please try again later.',
            title: 'Whoops'
        });

        errorDialog.show();


    };

    // Send the HTTP request
    loader.send();

}; // end the get data function
```

I've had to mask out  a few things for security reasons, but you should get the idea of what I'm trying to achieve!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Simon

Comment: could you add the output of the info() calls? And perhaps change the inner for loop to a different variable name (not sure if its good to reuse i in there)

Comment: This is the info output (a sample), which you can see, all of the items have the same initial ID.

[INFO] :   TOUR: 26395 26873 -0.151982000000 51.533740000000 BLACKBURN exhibit
[INFO] :   TOUR: 26395 22766 -0.152011000000 51.535223000000 HYACINTH MACAW animal

Comment: And the other info call for the tours themselves looks like this:

[INFO] :   33506 TOUR 1
[INFO] :   33505 TOUR 2
[INFO] :   26395 TOUR 3

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the outer loop finishes (i is at the last position, so is your tourID). After the loop the callback from the send function is called where you use tourID again. But at that time it is at the last ID, which is visible in your info().
The quickest (and its more secure) method is to include the id in the actual callback from the server, so in:

var tourDetails = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

shoulb be the tourID as a json field

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the API return, that would be the most logical, but I don't have the ability to change it. Any other way?

Comment: hm, you could make one request at a time so you know which id you have. This will lso help if you have many request at once, some servers will block to many open connections at once